# R: Difficulty for analysis of GSE7864 of NCBI GEO in Limma

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze GSE7864 and would like to know how miR34a, miR34b, and miR34c influence the gene expression, i.e., what is the Differentially expressed genes (**DGE**) caused by miR34a, miR34b, and miR34c, **respectively**?

The following is my code, but I am not sure how to construct a design matrix according to the  **tTarget**  information (i.e., targets frame according to Limma tutorial). I am trying to select a subset according to different Cy3 and the subsetted targets frame called **sTarget**, I know **sTarget** belongs to two-color with common reference designs (p37 in Limma tutorial), but using **sTargets** only can not build linear model in Limma since no enough replicates for each treatment. In this case, how can I get the DGE permuted by miR34a, miR34b, and miR34c, respectively? Or is there another way to obtain the **DGE** by using all arrays instead of just 3 like in **sTargets**? If so, how to contrast the `design matrix` and `contrast matrix`? I can not find similar examples in Limma tutorial.

If 2-fold change has used the measure the extent of DGE for GSM190752 (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM190752), then FC = 10^VAUE (since VALUE is LOG10 RATIO)? and the genes with abs(FC) > 2 are DGE permuted by miR34a?

Any help is appreciated!

Kevin

The code I used is listed:

```
#https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE7864
eset <- getGEO(filename = "GSE7864_series_matrix.txt.gz")
tCy3 = rep(c("A549H1", "HCT116Dicer", "TOV21GH1", "DLDDicer", "HeLa", "A549p53", "TOV21Gp53"), each = 4)
tCy5 = rep(c("Luc", "miR34a", "miR34b", "miR34c"), times = 7)
pd <- pData(eset)
tTarget <- data.frame(gsm = rownames(pd), Cy3 = tCy3, Cy5 = tCy5)
sCy3 = c("A549H1")
sCy5 = c("miR34a", "miR34b", "miR34c")
isSelected <- (tTarget$Cy3 %in% sCy3) & (tTarget$Cy5 %in% sCy5)
sTarget <- tTarget[isSelected, ]
```

Comment: Packages from Bioconductor have their own forums where you might get more help on answers specific to those packages. https://support.bioconductor.org/

Comment: @akaDrHouse thanks. I asked there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bioconductor,

## https://support.bioconductor.org/p/91258/#91332

From this, I got the answer.